# Get top n rows and sum the rest and call it others in Entity Framework linq lambda query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My data structure:

```
BrowserName(Name)   Count(Y)
MSIE9                 7        
MSIE10                  8           
Chrome                10        
Safari                11         
-- and so on------
```

What I'm trying to do is get the top 10 and then get the sum of rest and call it 'others'.

I'm trying to get the others as below but geting error..

```
Data.OrderBy(o => o.count).Skip(10)
    .Select(r => new downModel { modelname = "Others", count = r.Sum(w => w.count) }).ToList();
```

The error is at 'r.Sum(w => w.count)' and it says

> downModel does not contain a definition of Sum

The `downModel` just has string 'modelname' and int 'count'.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: y, I'm doing a take(n) and then concatenating the above others code to it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create just one model, then get the `sum` first and create your object:

```
var count = Data.OrderBy(o => o.count).Skip(10).Sum(x => x.count);
var model = new downModel { modelname = "Others", count = count };
```

Btw, `OrderBy` performs a sort in ascending order. If you want to get (or Skip) top results you need to use `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: :Tx,  The reason why I was doing was to 'concat' the take(n) rows with others 'row' both List<downModel>, but here I just have a single downModel, how do I add this row to the main take(n) rows list??

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to get the whole result - the top ten and the accumulated "others" - in a single database query like so:

```
var downModelList = context.Data
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.Count)
    .Take(10)
    .Select(d => new
    {
        Name = d.Name,
        Count = d.Count
    })
    .Concat(context.Data
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.Count)
        .Skip(10)
        .Select(d => new
        {
            Name = "Others",
            Count = d.Count
        }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => new downModel
    {
        modelName = g.Key,
        count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
    })
    .ToList();
```